# Print pdf from its server URL

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I have a pdf url and show it in webview using below code:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
         String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
         webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

i need to print this pdf without downloading the pdf.
In [this](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) document it tells only how to print a custom content by rendering it on a PDF canvas and sending thus created PDF document for printing. But has no information about how to send the webview pdf for printing?
Please anybody has any idea how to handle this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
        PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, final ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, final WriteResultCallback callback) {

            !!THIS MUST BE RUN ASYNC!!

            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try {
                input = new URL(YOUR URL HERE).openStream();
                output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
                //TODO Handle Exception
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO Handle Exception
            } finally {
                try {
                    input.close();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                return;
            }
            PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("NAME OF DOCUMENT").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();
            callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
        }
    };

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    printManager.print("JOB NAME", pda, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to capture a picture from your webView with the pdf and print this picture. You could use something like `WebView.capturePicture()`. Here is the original documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#capturePicture